# Custom command for multiple boxplots

Tags: pgfplots, macros, automation, boxplot

I have to include a lot of boxplots in my document and would like to automate this with a custom command. I'd like to be able to write something like this:

```
\boxplots[
  range={1,2,3,4,5},
  questions={
    {
       label=How many years ago did you start?
       key=How many years   
    },
    {
       label=How many hours do you spend playing?  
    }
  }
]
```

If the key argument isn't provided in the question list, it should default to the label argument. The command should look something like this (no proper LaTeX syntax):

```
\newcommand{\boxplots}[2] {
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
      xmin=MIN(#1),
      xmax=MAX(#1),
      xtick=#1
      ytick={1,...,LEN(#2)},
      yticklabels=
        \foreach reversed \q in #2
          \stepcounter{questioncounter}
          \textbf{Q.\thequestioncounter} {\q[label]}
    ]
      \foreach reversed \q in #2
        \addplot+[boxplot={box extend=0.5}]
          table [
            y={\q[key]}
          ]{\userstudyResults};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

The yticklabels should resolve to

```
{
  \textbf{Q.2} How many hours do you spend playing?,
  \textbf{Q.1} How many years ago did you start?
}
```

Problems I'm facing:

- reverse iterating over a list provided as argument
- calculating min and max of a list provided as argument
- calculating length of a list provided as argument
- named arguments
- default argument

Thanks for helping me out!